# Can´t set the correct size of UIScrollView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a chat application and for that I have a UIScrollView that has the chat itself. And this UIScrollView is inside another UIScrollView (that is there so that when the keyboard appears, the whole view gets scrolled up) that is disabled.

And so I want the text inside of the top UIScrollView to go all the way to the bottom (scrollable).

**EDIT: Like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJOxL.png**

But instead it looks like the scroll view doesn't go all the way down.

**EDIT: Like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8VXE.png**

Any help?

PS: I'm not modifying the scroll views via code in any way.

Thanks in advance,

Ricardo Amendoeira

Answer (score 0):

Is the Autosizing for the scrollview set as per this screen shot[image] and is Autoresize Subviews checked

Comment: You mean for the parent scroll view? Autoresixe is enabled but I can't   access the tool you're showing...It just pops when I go out of the size inspector... :S

Comment: not sure what you mean by pops - the control should be available on the 5th tab of the properties of the UIScrollView

Comment: yes, i know, but it's not there...I'll try to look for a solution and I'll get back to you

Comment: figured it out - turns out it didn't show because I was using Auto Layout. I had it set up like you sai but it doesn't work either... Have you checked the images?

Comment: from your first screen shot it would appear that your 2 scrollviews are not the same size. If they were you would only see 1 "UIScrollView" displayed

Comment: from your first screen shot it would appear that your 2 scrollviews are not the same size. If they were you would only see 1 "UIScrollView" displayed. Also are you setting the `contentSize` on the parent scrollview to accommodate the text you are trying to display? Finally instead of using 2 scrollviews have you considered using a `UITableView` to display the chat - http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately, I can't check on it today, but tomorrow I'll check it out and send you the feedback. Thanks again!